# Power Bi Query to web service - Error: Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value to type Record

Tags: json, rest, powerbi, powerquery

I have a web service that produces JSON.  We make jQuery REST calls to it and bind the data to Tables.

The service is C# WEBAPI with code like this:

```
  data = serializer.Serialize(rows);
  return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, lstFilteredData, Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter);
```

It produces JSON that like this:

```
"[{\"School\":\"UM \",\"Students\":\"500\"},{\"School\":\"FIU \",\"Students\":\"700\"},{\"School\":\"UF \",\"Students\":\"600\"},{\"School\":\"GT \",\"Students\":\"300\"}]"
```

We have jQuery REST that successfully consumes the service like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        url: 'https://myservices')),
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        crossDomain: true,
        //async: false,
        success: function (data){  onQuerySucceededWeb(data,true,param);}
    });
```

I'm tring to report on that data using Power Bi.  My PowerBi Query script is:
   let

```
Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://mywebservices")),
  #"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(Source),
    #"Expanded Value" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Value"),
    #"Expanded Value1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Expanded Value", "Value", {"School", "Students"}, {"Value.School", "Value.Students"})

in 
  #"Expanded Value1"
```

I'm getting this Error:

```
**Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value "[{"School":"UM      ..." to type Record.**
Details:
    Value=[{"School":"UM        ","Students":"500"},{"School":"FIU       ","Students":"700"},{"School":"UF        ","Students":"600"},{"School":"GT        ","Students":"300"}]
    Type=Type
```

[image]

Comment: What shows up if you use
= Text.FromBinary(Web.Contents("https://mywebservices"))
?

Comment: where exactly would I put that? In place of my entire Query script?

Comment: same.  Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value ""[{\"School\":\"UM  ..." to type Record.

Comment: What if you replace `Record.ToTable(Source)` with `Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)`, and then replace the next two steps with `Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"School", "Students"}, {"School", "Students"})`

Comment: Expression.Error: We cannot convert the value ""[{\"School\":\"UM  ..." to type List.
Details:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something might have broken on your server, because your JSON is a JSON string of an object. Your M query would have worked if the server hadn't stringified the JSON text, i.e. produced literally these bytes:

```
[{"School":"UM ","Students":"500"},{"School":"FIU ","Students":"700"},{"School":"UF ","Students":"600"},{"School":"GT ","Students":"300"}]
```

If you just want to get your M to work again, you can double-decode the JSON:

```
= Json.Document(Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://mywebservices")))
```

Comment: yeah, turned out we were double encoding in the service.

Answer (score 0):

Json.Document is returning a text value because the JSON being returned is a string. If you remove the quotes, Json.Document should parse it as a list of objects. This should work:

```
let
    Source = Web.Contents("https://mywebservices")
    Custom1 = Text.Range(Source, 1, Text.Length(Source) - 2),
    Custom2 = Json.Document(Custom1),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Custom2, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"School", "Students"}, {"School", "Students"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"`
```

This would fail if the web site ever returned an empty string.

Comment: This line: = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"School", "Students"}, {"School", "Students"})  Produced this error: Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type Binary to type Text.
Details:
    Value=Binary
    Type=Type

Comment: See actual screenshot of what comes back to from the service in a browser.

Comment: The error is actually on this line: = Text.Range(Source, 1, Text.Length(Source) - 2)

Comment: Oops, replace the fist step with `Source = Text.FromBinary(Web.Contents("https://mywebservices")),`. That should convert the web request to text, which can then turn the JSON string into a JSON array, which that can be turned into a list by Json.Document.

Comment: = Json.Document(Custom1)  DataFormat.Error: We found extra characters at the end of JSON input.
Details:
    Value=\
    Position=2

Comment: What does the first step return?